# Inserting data into a list using the for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create a list of even numbers from 1-100 by using a for loop on my variable *list100*.

> ```
> list100 = range(101)
>
> for num in list100:
>    list_even = []
>        if num % 2 == 0:
>            list_even.append(num)
>    print list_even
> ```

However, instead of getting [2,4,6,8,10,12,14 ....], I receive:

> ```
> [0]
> []
> [2]
> []
> [4]
> []
> [6]
>  .
>  .
>  .
>  .
> ```

Please help. 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the list at every iteration. Try:

```
list100 = range(101)
list_even = []   
for num in list100:
   if num % 2 == 0:
       list_even.append(num)
print list_even
```

though as @koffein points out in another answer,

```
range(2,101,2)
```

is more idiomatic.

Comment: The `print` needs to be moved out of the loop too.

Answer (score 1):

This way does not use a for loop, but is actually more idiomatic, I think.

```
# python 2.x
print range(2, 101, 2)

# python 3.x
print(list(range(2, 101, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to use list comprehension.

```
listeven = [x for x in range(101) if x % 2 == 0]
```

Nice and easy!

Answer (score 0):

```
list100 = range(101)
list_even = []
for num in list100:

     if num % 2 == 0:
             list_even.append(num)
     print list_even
```

this should work now. My fault also that i put the array inside loop so the item is resetting.

Comment: No. The OP would like to get a list of even numbers. Your code does not provide that, because you create a new list each loop.

Comment: Yes, it prints about 50 lists with one single element: `[0]
[2]
[4]
[6]
[8]
[10]
[12]
[14]
[16]
[18]
[20]
[22]...`